# How to send notification using FCM?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I wrote a cloud function, to listen for document creation in a collection, in my database

here is the function,

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
 
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().functions);
 
var newData;
 
exports.myTrigger = functions.firestore.document('FCM/{id}').onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    //
 
    if (snapshot.empty) {
        console.log('No Devices');
        return;
    }
 
    newData = 'hello';
 
    const deviceIdTokens = await admin
        .firestore()
        .collection('FCM')
        .get();
 
 var tokens = [];
 var i=0;
    for (var token of deviceIdTokens.docs) {
        tokens.push(token.data().ar1[i]);
        i++;
    }
    var payload = {
        notification: {
            title: 'push title',
            body: 'push body',
            sound: 'default',
        },
        data: {
            push_key: 'Push Key Value',
            key1: newData,
        },
    };
 
    try {
        const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
        console.log('Notification sent successfully');

        
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

This function works weirdly,

For example, sometimes it sends notification, and sometimes it does not.

It throws errors like " TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined".

I don't know how to resolve this issue,

In my arr1 field, i have an array of device tokens, to whom i want to send notifications to,

i want the function to send notifications only to the devices(using tokens) which are just created(in the  newly created document ),then delete the document.

I think it's sending notifications to all the documents at once.

I'm pretty new at node..

please help me out.

UPDATE:-
Here is my document structure

[image: Here is my document structure,]

Comment: Without seeing the specific data you're working with, and understanding what exactly you expect to happen with this data, there's not much we can do.  Please edit the question to walk through the problem more clearly showing actual data.

Comment: Hi, i have updated my question, i have added an image of my document structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type error coming from this line:

```
tokens.push(token.data().arr1[i]);
```

So all I can say is that sometimes token.data() doesn't have an arr1 attribute.